# How to have Number format to display '$' as well as decimals of 4 places in phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0.0000');
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_CURRENCY_USD_SIMPLE);
```

If I try this code the code to display '$' in the cell would work but not the decimal one, if i reverse it then code to display four decimal points would work but not the code to display '$'.

I am trying to write into excel file using PHPExcel library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number format codes are simply strings, you don't have to use the built-in values; but can set them to any valid MS Excel number format mask

e.g

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('$ #,##0.0000');
```

You can even be really clever with them

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('$ #,##0.0000;[Red]-$ #,##0.0000');
```

Comment: This is a standard MS Excel number format mask: the `;` acts as a separator between two masks, one to use when the value is 0 or more, the second to use when the value is negative.... the `[Red]` for the negative value mask means display the value in red text, and values of 0 or more are displayed in whatever font colour is set for the cell

Comment: You can find a short tutorial on how to define number format masks for Excel [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx) on the MS Office site